# How to connect to memcache server in php?

Tags: php, memcached

I am using a database server that has a different IP.  I have written this code for connecting to the memcache server

```
 $memcache->connect('localhost', '11211').
```

The following error occurred:

> Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to localhost:11211, Connection refused (111).

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error,I guess you didn't install Memcache Server.

When use Memcache,your need two apps

1. Memcache Server Application([click download](http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip) Win32 memcache version 1.2.6)
2. Memcache Client Application([enter to find](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/));

Use Step:

1. install Memcache Server and set up server.
2. create Memcache Client to connect Memcache just like your code .

more details to find
**Articles**:

[memcache缓存处理简介](http://huliuqing.github.io/2014-05-27-install-memcache-in-php.html) write by me in Chinese.

[How to install Memcached on Windows machine](http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine)

Comment: Whatever what OS you use,I think you need to check if Memcached Server start or not.If service started, try to find out if client work good.No more tips ,just try.